# Yii2 Auto Compress Extension not working on local environment

Tags: php, curl, yii2, virtualhost, yii-extensions

I am using **Yii2** on a local environment (a virtual host on my local machine) and trying to use the **Auto Compress Extension** (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-assets-auto-compress/) to combine and compress css and js files.

I installed it using composer and added the configuration code in the config file (web.php).

It seems to work because it creates the css file (same for js), but the file is empty. I tried to debug it and the problem seems to be in the curl lines of code:

```
$url     =   'http://my-virtual-host.local/css/style.css';
$ch      =   curl_init();
$timeout =   3;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The curl error i get is: **Couldn't resolve host name**.
I can correctly open in the browser the url this code tries to get using curl.